# Gatsby generates same avatar hundreds of times

Tags: gatsby, netlify

I have a blog with close to 200 hundred posts where one of the GraphQL queries fetches the author for each post (name, info, avatar). The problem is that I only have 2 authors in there but, when building the site, Gatsby is re-creating that avatar over and over...for each post. I can see it in Netlify's console log:

```
8:13:53 PM: warning
8:13:53 PM:                  The requested width "120px" for a resolutions field for
8:13:53 PM:                  the file /opt/build/repo/static/images/uploads/authors/rick.png
8:13:53 PM:                  was larger than the actual image width of 96px!
8:13:53 PM:                  If possible, replace the current image with a larger one.
8:13:53 PM: warning
8:13:53 PM:                  The requested width "120px" for a resolutions field for
8:13:53 PM:                  the file /opt/build/repo/static/images/uploads/authors/rick.png
8:13:53 PM:                  was larger than the actual image width of 96px!
8:13:53 PM:                  If possible, replace the current image with a larger one.
8:13:53 PM: warning
8:13:53 PM:                  The requested width "120px" for a resolutions field for
8:13:53 PM:                  the file /opt/build/repo/static/images/uploads/authors/morty.png
8:13:53 PM:                  was larger than the actual image width of 96px!
8:13:53 PM:                  If possible, replace the current image with a larger one.
8:13:53 PM: warning
8:13:53 PM:                  The requested width "120px" for a resolutions field for
8:13:53 PM:                  the file /opt/build/repo/static/images/uploads/authors/rick.png
8:13:53 PM:                  was larger than the actual image width of 96px!
8:13:53 PM:                  If possible, replace the current image with a larger one.
```

Apparently the avatar is smaller than the desired state but it's a good thing that I'm able to see where the holdup is.

I'm using fragments to query for the data but I see no reason why it would matter:

[post](https://github.com/QardsJs/qards/blob/30b33020bf03fe5561628188e1dc913c6a1cb854/src/fragments/post.ts#L65) which calls [author](https://github.com/QardsJs/qards/blob/30b33020bf03fe5561628188e1dc913c6a1cb854/src/fragments/author.ts#L22)

Any idea about how to make Gatsby understand that this avatar was just created milliseconds ago and re-use that one instead? I'm more concerned about the build command because 99% of the time I get a timeout in Netlify due to this.